# A host of competitive offers has / have been received

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Singular or plural verb?

A host of competitive offers have been received. (The sense is plural, so should we use 'have'? Or should it be 'has' to agree with the singular subject 'host'?)

Thanks.

Comment: it's singular, ez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically **has** is correct, as the subject of the sentence is "host." However, if you think this construction will sound odd to your audience, it may be preferable to rewrite the sentence to avoid it. For instance,

> Many competitive offers have been received.

or even

> We have received many competitive offers.

which also changes the voice from passive to active.

Answer (score 2):

Plural.  Use "have".  "Host" here has no substantive meaning, but just indicates plurality (in an extreme degree).

Comment: This is convincing to me when I consider similar constructions: a lot of, a multitude of.  It seems very natural (correct?) to use plural verb forms with all of these.